# jquery anonymous method

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var createRemoveButton = function(instance, removeMethod, removeIcon) {
                return $("<a>")
                    .attr("id", "remove_" + instance.offerKey + "_" + instance.offerConfigurationId)
                    .attr("style", "cursor: pointer;")
                    .click(function(event) {
                        removeMethod(instance.offerConfigurationId);
                    })
                    .append($("<img>").attr("src", removeIcon));
            };
```

how to use now `removeMethod`? can this `removeMethod` be JavaScript method? i am learning ajax anyonmous method and i am having problems with it.

Comment: Actually, there is no Ajax in this code. This is pure jQuery, which is just an extension of Javascript. So really, that code is already Javascript. Just create the function you need. Ajax refers to the method of fetching data from a remote page to be used on the current page to upadate the page without reloading it.

Comment: ok sorry my mistake jquery methods. But if i create removeMethod() this method is never called.

Comment: It's called when you click the button. Are you appending the element, and how are you calling `createRemoveButton`?

Comment: replace it with an alert command. If the alert shows then check your console for errors and report back.

Comment: Actually, there is no Ajax in this code. This is pure jQuery, which is just an extension of Javascript. So really, that code is already Javascript. Just create the function you need. Ajax refers to the method of fetching data from a remote page to be used on the current page to upadate the page without reloading it.

Comment: You have to pass a function reference as second argument to `createRemoveButton` if that's what you want to know. How are you calling `createRemoveButton` right now?

Comment: Please note that Java has nothing to do with JavaScript. They're entirely different languages. I've edited the term out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createRemoveButton` function has to be called just like this

```
createRemoveButton(instance, function(id){
        console.log(id);
    }, icon);
// I assume that instance and icon are defined already
```

second parameter - anonymous function, callback. It is the actually function wich will be called after `$("<a>")` is clicked.

also you able to avoid using of anonymous function - just define function you want to be called on element click. E.g.

```
var clickCallback=function(id){
    console.log(id);
};
    createRemoveButton(instance, clickCallback, icon);
```

I hope this is helpful

Comment: Technically, the function referred to by `clickCallback` is still anonymous because it does not have a name. The variable it is assigned to is not the name of the function. But whether a function is anonymous or not is not relevant for this question anyway.

Comment: yes, you are right. I was just hurry. I ment that function can be defined before passing it as param.
this would work as well as previous variant and wouldn't use anonymous functions
`function clickCallback(id){
    console.log(id);
}`